# jQuery smooth scrolling offset only on downscroll?

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset, scrolltop

I’m currently working on a website project and trying to implement a smooth scroll function via jQuery.

Here is my (working!) code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    var displace = 72;                    /* Vertical offset for scroll */
    var target = $(this.hash);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - displace}, 1000);
      return false;
  });
});
```

Because the site also has a header which transitions out of the viewport when scrolling DOWN and into the viewport when scrolling UP, I need to somehow accommodate for its visibility by offsetting the scroll target by a set amount, hence the `displace` variable.

As of right now, the `displace` variable is subtracted from `target.offset().top` regardless of scroll direction. How would I modify the above code so it is only subtracted when scrolling UP?

I thought about adding an `if else` statement in there, something along the lines of:

```
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
if (target.offset().top > scrollPos) {   /* On downscroll */
  scroll to target
} else {                                 /* On upscroll */
  scroll to target - displace
}
```

Any recommendations on getting this to work?

Thanks very much in advance!

Tim

Comment: Add your remaining codes.

Comment: @frnt as pertaining to the smooth scrolling function, this is the complete code (copied from another stackoverflow thread). the website i'm working on is of the one-page/parallax-scrolling kind and the function enables smooth scrolling between different anchors like

<a href="#about"></a>
<a href="#services"></a>
<a href="#contact"></a>

Comment: You need to add what you have tried.

Comment: @frnt added my code attempt that didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually got it to work using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var displace = 72;
    var target = $(this.hash);
    if (scrollPos > target.offset().top) {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - displace}, 1000);
        return false;
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
        return false; 
    }
  });
});
```